# Swiftui Tabview causes issues with Textfield

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

In SwiftUI, whenever I have a TextField inside a TabView, when I use a bluetooth barcode scanner, the Textfield never gets the correct value from the scanner, it always skips numbers. Sometimes it skips 50% of the barcode, sometimes just 1 or 2 numbers. This happens only when the TextField is inside a Tabview.

I never thought I would get stuck on something like this to be honest, maybe I am missing something very simple?

Here is a testcode:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Testview: View {
    @State private var searchProductText = ""
    @FocusState var productFieldIsFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView{
            HStack {
                TextField("", text: $searchProductText)
                    .focused($productFieldIsFocused)
                    .opacity(0)
                    .onSubmit {
                        print(searchProductText)
                        searchProductText = ""
                        productFieldIsFocused = true
                    }
            }.onAppear{
                productFieldIsFocused = true
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Testview_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Testview()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just noticed now that if i remove the "Hstack", the textfield works fine. I have no idea what is causing this tbh, would love some help here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if this is an intended behavior of SwiftUI, but when you use a `@State` variable in this structure, the `TextField` will be redrawn.
Since your scanner probably sends the inputs very quickly, the `TextField` could miss some characters.

In case you really need the `HStack`, you could try to move your state variable to an `ObservableObject`.

I found this out, when my cursor always jumped to the end of a `TextField` whenever I typed a character. This is how I solved it and it should help in your case as well:

```swift
class TextViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var txt = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = TextViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Text", text: $viewModel.txt)
            }
            .padding()
            .tabItem {
                Text("My Tab")
            }
        }
    }
}
```